# How can I use the Accordion (Collapsed Content) from jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm not familiar with jQuery and I would like to know how to add the Widget Accordion plugin to an HTML page.

I have linked the library files, but the browser says jQuery is not defined   - in the `jquery-ui.js:14`

It seems like there is not a declared function in the file. Do I have to declare it myself?

Comment: you need to include jQuery before jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link it is jquery ui accordion

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Right menú check the one you like and choose the code option of each example to se the source

Also you need jquery declared before jquery ui

Links should be in the correct order for jquery and jquery-ui so you call first jquery and then jquery-ui.

Comment: In order to define jquery before jquery ui you only need to add the source script to jquery and then the one for jquery ui

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Juan. 
It was a problem of link order! I make sens actually lol. Thanks and have a good one!